# Is there a chance installing a not yet released plugin corrupt eclipse installation

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, eclipse-indigo

I use Eclipse Indigo for java development but I want to experiment with scala. Since I have to download a nightly build to run on Eclipse : http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html is this safe ?

Is there a chance the plugin can corrupt my eclipse installation since the plugin is not a full blown release as yet ?

Comment: @ControlAltDel ok so safest to install over a seperate version of eclipse

Comment: heh... it's possible a plugin that IS released can corrupt your eclipse installation. In fact, I'd go so far to say that it's likely... Always back up your workspace before installing new stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run the latest Scala [milestone](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html) with no problems right now, which is probably safer than the nightly, and has better highlighting features.  If you do run into trouble you can always [revert to a previous installation state in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-123.htm), so I would consider it safe

The plugins architecture is designed so that Eclipse is protected from instability, unless they maliciously delete files on your installation, I doubt they would break Eclipse permanently.  To be extra careful you can make a backup of your eclipse directory.

Answer (score 2):

Nighly builds gives developers a chance to use latest features (not certified to be working on all environments) of the plugin which are not yet made available to end users. In general they work fine but there may be few undiscovered issues. You can always rollback your installation if something goes wrong or if you find any bugs.

If your aim is to learn or develop using scala, better to use stable build. A stable scala-ide plugin is available for Eclipse Indigo. Please visit 'http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html' for more details.